# Answer deleted for formatting?

Tags: discussion

This answer is formatted poorly, and has an overabundance of CAPITALS, but it seems like a legitimate answer, even if it's not the most helpful one.  I would suggest it should be edited and improved rather than deleted:

https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/9930/92

> MANY SLAVES WERE ALLOWED TO BRING THEIR MUSICAL.INSTRUMENTS THAT.PLAYED THEM.ON THE SLAVE SHIPS THE STINKING SLAVE HOLDERS FIGURED OUT THST IF A SLAVE PLAYED MUSIC AND SANG THEY WPULD BE MORE PRODUCTIVE, IN WHAT WORK THEY WERE DOING, JAZZ CAME FROM BLUES..BLUES HAD A BABY THEY CALLED IT ROVK AND ROLL, JAZZ CAME BEFORE R AND R LONG TIME BEFORE, GERMAN BANDS SAT IN WITH X SLAVES IN.NEW yourk HARLEM.MIXED BLUES AND CLASSICAL.together to get a new sound in the 50s thats when Harlem roenaissance I married a Delta blues arkansas blues legand and this is more truth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was flagged as not an answer which it really did not try to address the core of the question which is about the 12 bar blues style. The combination of not really an answer plus the poor formatting made it an easy flag to handle as a delete.

I personally don't think the content is salvageable as is even if it was formatted better as again it didn't address the question asked. It talked a bit about blues history, but nothing really addressed the question.

Comment: I guess that's fair...